# Как сохранить данные в файл, полученные в запросе сервлетом?

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

Есть проект с классом ServletTest, который планируется использовать в Tomcat.

Как сохранить данные в файл, полученные в get или post запросе?

Или взять данные из файла, которые будут использованы в обработке сервлетом?

Comment: `Files.readAllBytes` и там же `write`; или с сервлетами что-то особенное надо?

Comment: если вопрос -- как лучше хранить, то в ceph/s3, например можно

Comment: Например сервлет запущен в Tomcat. Где в этом случае должны лежать файлы для хранения?

Comment: Есть человек в проекте, который обеспечивает сохранность данных. Он должен сказать: мы бакапим папку "/our-data", или вот по такому адресу настроен ceph-s3, или nfs, и т. п.

Comment: Sergei Kirjanov, нет никаких других людей, я просто хочу понять как это работает и сделать сам.

Comment: Замечательно, значит определите, что вы будете делать, чтобы не потерять файлы в результате поломки оборудования или ошибки (примеры выше). Просто сами определите, где на сервере будут лежать ценные вещи, а где темп.